# Darts web socket connection problem with ssl

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

I want to use a web socket on Flutter.
I can easily connect to non-SSL API. But when connecting to an API with SSL get the following error.

> WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException:
>   HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
>   WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))

[image]

I tried using SecureSocket, but it doesn't allow adding parameters in SecureSocket.